# How to get filename of of active tab in a Tab View?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC program that is sort of like a text editor: http://www.dogdaysrpg.com/screen.png

What I want is to get the filename of the current working tab as a string. So for example, in the picture above, the string would be "Emergence1".

How do I get the filename used on the active tab?

Comment: Why don't you remember the name of the file? You must have known it once to set the tab caption?

Comment: Sorry....much of the infrastructure was created by the MFC wizard. So I don't know how that part is set up.

Comment: If you don't know, what chance do we have? I suggest it is time you got to know your program.

Comment: I was hoping someone would know the code generated by the MFC wizard to pinpoint me how i might change it...

Comment: Well, you were actually hoping that somebody would guess that you'd used this wizard because there's no mention of it in the question. Seriously, how can you expect to write software without having knowledge and understanding of your code. Don't hold back. Read the code and work out what it is doing. Consider doing without the wizard. Asking us to help you work with something that you won't even try to understand seems a bit much.

Comment: Ok fair enough....i didn't mention it in the question...but is it possible to at lease tell me what is the class name(based on the picture) of the tab control implemention?

Comment: @user3126297 `MFC` brrrrrr! `MFC wizard generated classes` run!run!run! Getawayasfarasyoucaninshortesttime!!

Comment: Even if I could, I would not. I think it will do you good to get to know your own program.

Comment: well to be fair, telling me would help me get to know my own program because by looking through that part of the code, it would shed some light on how it works...I'll admit though that this question requires you guys to go out of the way to help...

Comment: @user3126297 Seriously: Usage of MFC is a (legally?) valid reason to resign that job immediately! Well, I've been learning COBOL once ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem.

I needed to get the title of the current active document.

In order to retrieve the current active document, use the following code:

```
CDocument * CEmergenceView::GetDoc()
{
      CMDIChildWnd * pChild =
          ((CMDIFrameWnd*)(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd))->MDIGetActive();

      if ( !pChild )
          return NULL;

      CDocument * pDoc = pChild->GetActiveDocument();

      if ( !pDoc )
         return NULL;

      // Fail if doc is of wrong kind
      if ( ! pDoc->IsKindOf( RUNTIME_CLASS(CDocument) ) )
         return NULL;

      return (CDocument *) pDoc;
}
```

Then when you retrieve the document, call GetTtile, i.e:

```
CDocument * currentDoc = GetDoc();
CString title = currentDoc->GetTitle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the title for a specific view is pretty simple: `GetParentFrame()->GetTitle()`.

If you don't know which view is currently selected, finding that is actually a little trickier. There's an `OnActivateView` that's called when a view is activated or deactivated. You'll need to add an overload of that to keep track of which one was most recently activated. Then to find it, you'll enumerate your views (with your document's `GetFirstViewPosition`, `GetNextView`) to find the one that's active.